# UIImageView not updating image

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I am trying to make a simple "Profile" view that allows the user to change his picture. the image picker loads the gallery successfully and i choose the new image then write it to documents directory to load it in next launch, the problem is the imageview is not refreshing with the new image until i exit the app and relaunch again (only viewDidLoad works but viewWillAppear is loading the old image although it is overwritten!) any ideas?

```
import UIKit

class Profile: UIViewController,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate {

var imagePicker:UIImagePickerController=UIImagePickerController()
var pickedImage:UIImage?

let filemgr = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

@IBOutlet weak var profilepic: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var lblheight: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var lblwidth: UILabel!



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    profilepic.layer.borderWidth=1
    profilepic.layer.borderColor=UIColor.blackColor().CGColor

    let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self, action:Selector("imageTapped:"))
    profilepic.userInteractionEnabled = true
    profilepic.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
    imagePicker.delegate=self


    if profileImageExists()
    {
        pickedImage=UIImage(named: Operations.getDocumentsDirectory().stringByAppendingPathComponent("profile.png"))!

    } else {
        pickedImage=UIImage(named:"camera.png")!
    }

    profilepic.image=pickedImage



}






func imageTapped(img: AnyObject)
{
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        imagePicker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary
        presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion:
            {
                self.lblheight.text="completed"
                print ("completed image tab")
            }
    )
}


override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
pickedImage=UIImage(named:         Operations.getDocumentsDirectory().stringByAppendingPathComponent("profile.png"))!
    profilepic.image=pickedImage



}


// MARK: - UIImagePickerControllerDelegate Methods

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        profilepic.contentMode = .ScaleToFill

        profilepic.image = pickedImage



            if let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(pickedImage) {
                let filename = Operations.getDocumentsDirectory().stringByAppendingPathComponent("profile.png")



                data.writeToFile(filename, atomically: true)

                             }


    }

    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}



func profileImageExists() -> Bool
{

    if let profileImage=UIImage(named: Operations.getDocumentsDirectory().stringByAppendingPathComponent("profile.png"))
    {
        return true
    }
    else
    {
    return false

    }

}




}
```

Comment: so when u choose the image from picker, and dismiss it, the imageview is not loading the new image ?

Comment: no, the old image is still shown, but when i close the app and re-open it, the new image appears correctly

Comment: that's what i said, the imageview is not showing the new image after u dismiss the picker. am I correct ?

Comment: did u put a breakpoint, and see that if condition executes after u dismiss the picker?

Comment: the break point shows it is still holding the old image, which is not exist in the directory!

Comment: can u see the the new image at the breakpoint ?

Comment: no, but i was catching the height and width of the image, it shows the old image's dimensions

Comment: you can see the image at the breakpoint. you need to tap on the eye icon to see the image. Put the breakpoint after the if condition in that method.

Comment: The image is cached because you are using `UIImage(named:)`. Have a look at my answer.

Comment: thanks a lot @joern, it worked

Comment: thanks @Mr.T for you time :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loading an UIImage with `init(named:)` caches the image. So as long as the image name does not change or the system is emptying the cache (for example when you restart the app) the image will be used from the cache and not loaded again.

Try to use `init(contentsOfFile:)` instead to load the image.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your imagePickerController method. You have used  pickedImage as an instance variable and an local optional variable. I have used newImage instead.

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    if let newImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        profilepic.contentMode = .ScaleToFill
        profilepic.image = newImage
        pickedImage = newImage


        if let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(newImage) {
                let filename = Operations.getDocumentsDirectory().stringByAppendingPathComponent("profile.png")
                data.writeToFile(filename, atomically: true)

        }
    }

    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```