# ImageView won't update with new image

Tags: ios, swift, image, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to select an image from the user's phone and update an image view with said image.

The problem I am having is that it won't update the image. It does get there as I added a breakpoint and it hit the breakpoint, and the image view can change image as I manually tried changing it elsewhere.

But it refuses to work when I need it.

My image view:

```
    lazy var profilePictureImageView: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "DefaultUser")
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill

        imageView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSelectProfilePicture)))
        imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        return imageView
    }()
```

The code to update the image via picking a photo on the device:

```
import UIKit

extension ProfileVC: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    func handleSelectProfilePicture() {
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.delegate = self
        picker.allowsEditing = true
        present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
         var selectedImageFromPicker: UIImage?
         if let editedImage = info["UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage"] as? UIImage {
             selectedImageFromPicker = editedImage
         }
         else if let originalImage = info["UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"] as? UIImage {
             selectedImageFromPicker = originalImage
         }
        if let selectedImage = selectedImageFromPicker {
             profilePictureImageView.image = selectedImage
        }
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

[EDIT] One thing I have discovered is if I try it on a different VC with a different image view it works as intended. The only main difference I can see between the two VC's is the one I want it to work on but won't also extends 'UIPickerViewDelegate' and 'UIPickerViewDataSource'. Could there be conflict?

Comment: What if you removed *lazy* from *profilePictureImageView*?

Comment: @dfd but you need lazy so you can target self in the gesture recogniser

Comment: Why do you need `imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`? Are you setting some constraints programmatically? Can you provide all of the code?

Comment: I personally don't do things this way, thus my question. I've seen how lazy affects vars - and I was wondering if passing things off to a different VC was deallocating the image view just when you were needing it. (I'm likely wrong, but wanted to offer a suggestion.)

Comment: @timaktimak Yes, I am adding all constraints programmatically, I do not use storyboards.
I could provide all the code but theres quite a lot of it?

Comment: @dfd It's all in the same VC, just I made an extension of the VC for ease of reading the code. And more annoyingly I know this works as I've done it before :(

Comment: Curious... I just added your code to a fresh UIViewController... the only thing I did that you do not have shown is to add in `viewDidLoad()` this `let ppiv = profilePictureImageView` and `self.view.addSubview(ppiv)` ... it worked fine, except the image view frame changes to the size of the loaded photo. (edits - formatting - grrr)

Comment: @DonMag Did you try it my edit?

Comment: @KyloR - here's my entire view controller code. https://gist.github.com/DonMag/dea68a0bef5c97980412b716777fdfb2 Only notable difference is my default image filename.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this, it worked for me:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    profilePictureImageView.image = croppedImage
    profilePictureImageView.setNeedsDisplay()
}
```

Essentially you need to specify that you want to update the image via

```
profilePictureImageView.setNeedsDisplay()
```

Answer (score 4):

You want to do all UI updating - such as changing the image - on the main thread:

```
   if let selectedImage = selectedImageFromPicker {
         DispatchQueue.main.async {
             profilePictureImageView.image = selectedImage
         }
    }
```

Should do it.

Comment: This didn't work sadly. One thing I have discovered though is if I try it on a different VC with a different image view it works as intended. The only main difference I can see between the two VC's is the one I want it to work on but won't also extends `UIPickerViewDelegate` and `UIPickerViewDataSource`. Could there be conflict?

Answer (score 1):

I am having no issues with this code, which I have tried to replicate yours as much as possible.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    lazy var imageView: UIImageView = {
       let iView = UIImageView()
        iView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill

        iView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSelectProfilePicture)))
        iView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        return iView
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.addSubview(imageView)
        self.imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .height, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 1.0).isActive = true
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .width, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 1.0).isActive = true
    }

    func handleSelectProfilePicture() {
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.delegate = self
        picker.allowsEditing = true
        present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

extension ViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

        var selectedImageFromPicker: UIImage?

        if let editedImage = info["UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage"] as? UIImage {
            selectedImageFromPicker = editedImage
        }

        else if let originalImage = info["UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"] as? UIImage {
            selectedImageFromPicker = originalImage
        }

        if let selectedImage = selectedImageFromPicker {
            imageView.image = selectedImage
        }

        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

The issue must be caused by something else in your code. I have used a lazy var the same as yourself. Can you try simplifying your code to this and see if it works or post the rest of your code. What constraints do you have set?

Comment: What's the standard for sharing code, as it's a little too much to copy and paste. Also, as mentioned in my edit, do you think it could be down to my VC having UIPickerViewDelegate as well?

Comment: It depends on the project and your personal views really. you could provide a github link if its nothing commercial or private. or you could use github private or bitbucket and invite people individually so that they can try to solve the issue. So you have the delegate in the vc and the extension? I cant see it causing the issue myself but best to only use it where needed. if your class definition already states that it conforms to the protocol and your just using the extension for readability, you can just do extension without adding it again... extension ViewController {} works too

Comment: Can I add you to a private github repo? (or anyone else willing to try figure this out)

Comment: sure, my github username is martinjkelly

Comment: I've found the source of the issue. When you set a UIImageView's image property with UIImage(named: "whatever") it caches it so even when you update it, it uses the cached version. Just trying to work out how

Comment: Wow! Okay, how did you go about finding out that was the problem? I wouldn't know where to start..

Comment: @KyloR - if you're still working on this, I'm happy to take a look. My GitHub name is the same as here... DonMag

Comment: Bit of educated googling lol. I come across this answer which seems to be the common workaround. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34512918/uiimageview-not-updating-image. It says to use local images outside of the assets file and use contentsOfFile to init your images. I'll check later on to see if I can find a more elegant way.

Comment: Well thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction!! I shall check out the link myself and see what I can figure out with my limited swift knowledge :)

Comment: @DonMag you're more than welcome to browse the code as well

Comment: I changed the UIImageView to be set using contentsOfFile, and that works fine and still loads the default photo. Trying to change the photo still fails though. 

Also something else I noticed, if I change the photo by another means (for example I tried changing the photo every time I pressed cancel on the picker menu for age/location etc) the photo changes just fine..?

Comment: ok - I created an account... something is wrong with your referencing profilePictureImageView... if you put this line `print("creating profilePictureImageView?")` inside `lazy var profilePictureImageView: UIImageView = {}` you'll see that it gets called ***again*** after you set the new image.

Comment: have you pushed these changes? I'll have another look

Comment: Interesting.. okay let me implement the code to store the new selected image in firebase, and then in the viewdidappear for the VC, I will make it check firebase and update the photo if needed...! Hopefully that will fix it :)

Comment: Further looking... `viewDidLoad()` in ProfileVC.swift is called again on return from the image picker.... which is, in turn, calling `addSubviews()` again... which is, evidently, creating a new instance of `profilePictureImageView`

Comment: @DonMag why does this happen with `ProfileVC`, but if I change it to `LoginVC` so I'm changing the logo picture then everything works normally? `LoginVC` also creates the default logo in `viewDidLoad()`

Comment: Not entirely sure -- yet :) It *looks* like your subclassed `UITabBarController` is re-creating its VCs on `viewWillAppear` ... which is being called when you dismiss the image picker.

Comment: @DonMag Yeeesss!! I changed the `UITabBarController` to create the VC's in `viewDidLoad()` instead and this seems to have fixed the problem!

Comment: @KyloR Woo Hoo :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137774/discussion-between-kylor-and-donmag).

Comment: well spotted @DonMag

Comment: @ISS This question and answer are both 2 years old, I would suggest raising your own question with your specific issue and we can try to help, things  can change over a 2 year period, especially with iOS and Swift

Comment: good to hear, sorry the reply was so late, i was on holiday :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to set modalPresentationStyle tooverCurrentContext
Like the sample below

```
 let myPickerController = UIImagePickerController()
    myPickerController.delegate = self
    myPickerController.sourceType =  UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary
    **myPickerController.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext**
    myPickerController.delegate = self
    present(myPickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another case that might be useful for someone:

I had the same problem, except my ImageView was on a TableViewCell.
Work is done on main thread.
Nothing worked including calling `imageView.setNeedsDisplay()` and even on every superview.

What did help, for some odd reason, was only calling `setNeedsLayout()` on the **cell** containing the imageView.
I checked the layout and all the views are in the same order and positions before this call and after.

I'm not sure as to why this worked and nothing else, so if anyone has any ideas, it would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What I tried myself right now and it worked was to go inside `UITabBarController`, and create all `viewControllers` inside `viewDidLoad()` and not inside `viewWillAppear()` where it originally was.

One note, you have to do it with `dispatch` otherwise, the app will crash

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.setupViewControllers()
    }
}
```

Looks like because the viewController were created inside `viewWillAppear()`, upon `uiPicker` dismiss the `viewControllers` would load again and the selected image would be lost.

Answer (score 0):

First make the existing image value to null using

```
        imageView.image = nil
```

Then add the new image to image view

```
        let yourImage = UIImage(named: "your_image_name")
        imageView.image = yourImage
```

This worked for me